# Prevent back button load the hash in url instead on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a website where the subscription form will appear when user click on a subscribe button and will add # to the url(http://signature-bravo.dev/#subscribe_form).

My question is how to make the page reload (usually when user click back button on browser) without showing the subscription form even the url is still http://signature-bravo.dev/#subscribe_form. It just appear when user click on a subscribe button.

How to archive this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery this should work:

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
    window.location.hash = '';
});
```

It still leaves the '#', but nothing after.

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can use this code:

```
window.onunload=function(){
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Comment: try your answer but still not working.. here is the live site: http://bravo.signatureasia.com/#subscribe_form

Comment: which one did you try and which browser did you use? I tried it in Chrome Version 37.0.2062.103 and it worked perfectly. Try putting it in head tag in a separate `<script>` tag.

Comment: I try with both solution up there in my chrome but still when i clicking back button, it still can reload #subscribe_form